# Some problems on sphinx for Java API

Tags: java, sphinx

I'm new to [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/about/sphinx/), and I've encountered a few problems:

**$1** After setting `max_matches = 200` in class searchd in csft.conf, I called

`org.sphx.api.test.main(new String[]{"-h", "127.0.0.1","-i", "magnet","-p", "9312", "-l", "100", "keyword"});`

in a java main method. The error returned is

**Error: searchd error: per-query max_matches=1000 out of bounds (per-server max_matches=200)**

As you can see, I've added the param: `-l = 100`, what else should I set to prevent this error in Java?

**$2** I want to use `sortMode = SphinxClient.SPH_SORT_TIME_SEGMENTS` to have the search result ordering by time desc. My attribute is written like this in csft.conf:

sql_attr_timestamp=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`upload_time`) as dt

Could anyone tell me how can I set the attribute in Java code? I've tried to set the `sortClause` String in java, but it always said that **Attribute XXX has not been found**.

**$3** I want to know whether `SphinxClient` in Java is thread safe, becaust I don't like to create a SphinxClient instance every time a person do a query.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the class you are using is https://code.google.com/p/sphinxtools/source/browse/trunk/src/org/sphx/test/test.java?r=2
   then the function never even inspects 'argv'. It hardcodes all the variables. There is nothing passed as the third param to setLimits
2. `sql_attr_timestamp` simply accepts a column name, no functions or anything. The function call HAS to be in the main `sql_query`
3. My java is very rusty, but would have to say no. It stores all sort of state in private varibles. Multiple threads using the client at once will clober them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer！I've found the `setLimits` method.